# JMeter Plugins Manager Failed to download plugins repository

Tags: jmeter

I can't connect with JMeter Plugins Manager.
I have a new version 5.
JMeter is working normally but I can't use manager.

> Error's technical details: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the steps listed in the link in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in the user.Properties file & you should be able to access the Plugin Manager

jpgc.repo.address=http://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks. Can you explain why this is the solution, please?

Comment: Because it uses HTTP protocol to get to the plugin repo.  This workaround solution also worked for me, too.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check [SSL Configuration](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/#SSL-Configuration) solution:

> If you got an exception `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty` it possible can be fixed by set the path to original cacert certificate file. This file can be found in the following paths:

```
 - `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts.original`  
 - `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts.original`  
 - `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`
 - `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\ (eg c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\security\)`
```

And launch JMeter with additional parameters to pass path to this file:

```
JVM_ARGS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat
```

An easy way to do so is by creating a file named `setenv.bat` in the `jmeter\bin` directory. Such a file could look like:

```
rem This is the content of bin\setenv.bat,
rem it will be called by bin\jmeter.bat
set JVM_ARGS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

In addition, you may select and use your plugins with JMeter Plugins Manager [this way](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/03/select-plugins-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

Comment: 2019-02-07 13:03:20,597 WARN o.j.r.PluginManagerMenuItem: Failed to load plugin updates info
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]

Answer (score 0):

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect jmeter-plugins.org:443
```

Copy all public certificates in separate pem files.
Then find your certificate store as example cacerts.
Import all above pems in it using

```
keytool -import -alias 1p -file 1.pem -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Then start jmeter using

```
JVM_ARGS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts" ./jmeter.sh
```